# Non-linear systems convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system

Is there a way of being sure that **simple** iteration schemes, such as Gauss-Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel will converge for **non-linear** systems? I understand that for linear systems, the matrix A has to be diagonally dominant for G-J iteration, etc. to converge but can't seem to find anything online about convergence for non linear systems. An example may help:

$x(A-3x-4y)=0$ ;

$y(B-2x-y)=0$

Thanks, been struggling for a while.

Comment: Your example isn't appropriate as you can factor out $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: Sorry but that is totally out of my scope! I don't quite understand it

Comment: The non-linear world is much more difficult than linear algebra, you can't avoid it. You should change your example. Also note that nonlinear systems aren't representable by a matrix.

Comment: x+y=1 ; x^2 + y^2 = 1.  But how do we know these converge?

Comment: I already gave you a link. You can't bypass it. Also beware that you cannot discuss convergence as long as you have not specified how you iterate. This is missing in your question.

Comment: For this example, G-S iteration:   x (j+1) = 1 - y(j)   ;  y (j+1) = sqrt( 9 - x(j+1) ^2)

Comment: For convenience, it is easier to eliminate a variable and consider $y_{j+1}=\sqrt{9-(1-y_j)^2}$.

Comment: In convex optimization, convergence for many important iterative methods such as the Douglas-Rachford method is shown by expressing the method as fixed-point iteration for a certain nonlinear operator, then invoking convergence results for fixed-point iteration. One important convergence result is that if an operator is firmly nonexpansive and has a fixed point then fixed-point iteration converges to a fixed point. I'd be interested in learning what results are available for Gauss-Seidel iteration.

Answer (score 0):

We focus on the second example given by the OP
 $$x_{j+1}=1-y_j,\\y_{j+1}=\sqrt{9-x_{j+1}^2}.$$

We can eliminate $x$ to reduce to a single variable problem

$$y_{j+1}=\sqrt{9-(1-y_j)^2}=f(y_j).$$

By solving the equation, we known that

$$y=\frac{\sqrt{17}+1}2$$ is a fixed-point.

As the derivative

$$|f'(y)|=\left|\frac{1-y}{\sqrt{9-(1-y)^2}}\right|=\left|\frac{\sqrt{17}-9}8\right|<1$$ at the fixed point, linear convergence is guaranteed (we have a contracting map).

Anyway, we have to discuss the attraction basin of this fixed-point.

$f$ is defined over $[-2,4]$, has a single maximum at $(1,3)$ and range $[0,3]$. $f$ is also convex. So after one iteration, $f(y)\in[0,3]$, and after two iterations $f(y)\in[\sqrt5,\sqrt8]$, where the function is monotonous.

Then the largest slope in this range is at $\left(\sqrt8,\dfrac{1-2\sqrt2}{2\sqrt[4]2}\right)$, so that the Lipschitz constant $0.8$ holds. Convergence is guaranteed starting from any $y\in[-2,4]$.